# video.js video does not stream in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video.js

recently I tried to use video.js for playing my videos. It works quite fine but there is one exception: In IE9 the videos are not streamed; it takes a long time until they start playing.
Example here:
http://www.ulrichbangert.de/orchid/phalaenopsis/2013-03-20_Phal_I_Hsin_Salmon.php
I used Freemake Video Converter to create the videos (HTML5 mode).
Best regards - Ulrich

Comment: In the meantime I have solved the problem: When I use HTML5 video of course I also have to use the HTML5 doctype!

Answer (score 0):

For others still having problems ... at least for the wordpress plugin ...

- the plugin sets the mp4 type to video/mp4  ... IE9 does not like this
- change the type for mp4 to ... video/x-m4v

I suspect the same may be true of other types if they won't stream in IE ...

Note: there are other issues with IE9 in that some mp4 videos are organized in a way that makes IE read the entire file before playing it.  Search for qt-faststart ... but the video type was preventing my videos in wordpress from starting in IE.  You might try setting preload to false for IE.